# Use segments function to draw lines

Tags: r, regression, segments

I am trying to plot lines between my observed value and fitted value. But somehow I keep on getting error. I am using `segments` to do this. Below is my script:

```
mdl<-lm(yld ~ year,data=asm);summary(mdl)
plot(yld ~ year,data=asm,pch=16,xlab="Year",ylab=expression(paste("Raw rice yield (kg/ha)")))
abline(mdl)
x0 <- x1 <- mdl$mdl$year
y0 <- mdl$mdl$yld
y1 <- fitted(mdl)
segments(x0, y0, x1, y1, col="red", lwd=2)

Error in segments(x0, y0, x1, y1, col = "red", lwd = 2) : 
invalid first argument
```

Could anyone tell me what am I doing wrong here? When I run `x0` it shows NULL. Same for `x1` and `y1` (NULL). Is this the problem and how do I correct it

Thanks

Comment: Did you mean to use `mdl$model` instead of `mdl$mdl`?

Comment: Hey. Thanks a lot. This was the problem. I thought both of them should be mdl.